# Bugs with large dataframe filters & view in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt, selectinput

I'm trying do make a shiny application with interdependant `selectInput()`, it seems to work fine with a "little" dataframe but crash with a "large" dataframe.
Here is my example, with two dataframes : First, you can launch the application with the two dataframe, just comment the one you dont want to show in output.
Is it a problem with performance, I have to use `data.table` ? or it's `updateSelectInput()` functions problem ?

Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
#              letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 1000), Numbers = as.character(1:(26*1000)),
             letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(df$LETTERS))),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(df$Numbers))),
                 selectInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(df$letters)))),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  goButton <- reactive({
    # Data

    df1 <- df

    if (length(input$filter1)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]
    }

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)



    if (length(input$filter2)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter3", choices = c("All", df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df1$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)

    if (length(input$filter3)){
      df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", df1$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)


    datatable(df1)
  })

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
    goButton()

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried the same example with a `textOutput()` function to show dimension of the output dataframe and get some issues, I think it's a bug with the `updateSelectInput` function

Comment: The problem is the `selectInput`s in general. They don't seem to be able to handle so many choices. If you want you can use the filter option in DT. I can post a solution with that if you want?

Comment: Thanks @EliBerkow, I know the filter option in DT package. In my case, the app crashes with the large dataframe, how could you improve the `reactive` function ? tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced your selectInputs with pickerInputs from the shinyWidgets package and it runs much quicker - it's not fast but it works. I made a few other changes like not updating on startup:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

# df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 2), Numbers = as.character(1:52),
#              letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

df <- tibble(LETTERS = rep(LETTERS, 1000), Numbers = as.character(1:(26*1000)),
             letters = paste(LETTERS, Numbers, sep = ""))

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Title"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(width=3,
                     pickerInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = TRUE, choices = unique(df$LETTERS), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
                     pickerInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = TRUE, choices = unique(df$Numbers), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)),
                     pickerInput("filter3", "Filter 3", multiple = TRUE, choices = unique(df$letters), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))),

        mainPanel(
            DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    goButton <- reactive({
        # Data

        df1 <- df

        if(length(input$filter1)+length(input$filter2)+length(input$filter3) == 0) {
            if(!is.null(isolate(input$tableprint_rows_current))){
                updatePickerInput(session, "filter1", choices = unique(df1$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
                updatePickerInput(session, "filter2", choices = unique(df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)
                updatePickerInput(session, "filter3", choices = unique(df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)
            }
            return(df1)
        }

        if (length(input$filter1)){
            df1 <- df1[which(df1$LETTERS %in% input$filter1),]

            # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
            updatePickerInput(session, "filter2", choices = unique(df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)
            updatePickerInput(session, "filter3", choices = unique(df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)
        }


        if (length(input$filter2)){
            df1 <- df1[which(df1$Numbers %in% input$filter2),]

            updatePickerInput(session, "filter1", choices = unique(df1$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
            updatePickerInput(session, "filter3", choices = unique(df1$letters), selected = input$filter3)
        }


        if (length(input$filter3)){
            df1 <- df1[which(df1$letters %in% input$filter3),]

            updatePickerInput(session, "filter1", choices = unique(df1$LETTERS), selected = input$filter1)
            updatePickerInput(session, "filter2", choices = unique(df1$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)
        }


        return(df1)
    })

    output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(goButton())

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Eli, It's better but still not fast as I want. I think Iwill choose the cascade `selectInput` for doing this type of application.

Comment: I found another option but the code is not vey nice because I wrote all possibilities what do you think ? thanks

Comment: It works but I see what you mean - it's really messy

Answer (score 1):

I find another option with the `uiOutput` and `renderUI` functions, not beatiful as `updateSelectInput` solution but it works

```
df <- structure(list(Continent = c("Africa", "Africa", "Asia", "Asia",
                                   "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia",
                                   "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe",
                                   "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe",
                                   "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe",
                                   "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe",
                                   "Europe", "Europe", "North America", "North America", "North America",
                                   "North America", "North America", "North America", "North America",
                                   "North America", "North America", "North America", "North America",
                                   "North America", "North America", "North America", "North America",
                                   "North America", "North America", "North America", "North America",
                                   "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania",
                                   "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania", "Oceania",
                                   "Oceania", "Oceania", "South America", "South America", "South America",
                                   "South America", "South America", "South America", "South America",
                                   "South America", "South America", "South America", "South America",
                                   "South America"), Country = c("Algeria", "Angola", "India", "India",
                                                                 "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "Cambodia",
                                                                 "Iraq", "Israel", "Japan", "Jordan", "Pakistan", "Philippines",
                                                                 "Qatar", "Belgium", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia",
                                                                 "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland",
                                                                 "France", "Georgia", "Monaco", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway",
                                                                 "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "San Marino", "Serbia", "Slovakia",
                                                                 "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United States",
                                                                 "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
                                                                 "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
                                                                 "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States",
                                                                 "United States", "Panama", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia",
                                                                 "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Australia",
                                                                 "Fiji", "Kiribati", "Marshall Islands", "Micronesia", "Nauru",
                                                                 "New Zealand", "Palau", "Papua New Guinea", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands",
                                                                 "Tonga", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu", "Argentina", "Bolivia", "Brazil",
                                                                 "Chile", "Colombia", "Ecuador", "Guyana", "Paraguay", "Peru",
                                                                 "Suriname", "Uruguay", "Venezuela"), State = c("State_Algeria",
                                                                                                                "State_Angola", "Andhra Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam",
                                                                                                                "Bihar", "Chhattisgarh", "Goa", "Gujarat", "Haryana", "State_Cambodia",
                                                                                                                "State_Iraq", "State_Israel", "State_Japan", "State_Jordan",
                                                                                                                "State_Pakistan", "State_Philippines", "State_Qatar", "State_Belgium",
                                                                                                                "State_Bosnia and Herzegovina", "State_Bulgaria", "State_Croatia",
                                                                                                                "State_Cyprus", "State_Czech Republic", "State_Denmark", "State_Estonia",
                                                                                                                "State_Finland", "State_France", "State_Georgia", "State_Monaco",
                                                                                                                "State_Montenegro", "State_Netherlands", "State_Norway", "State_Poland",
                                                                                                                "State_Portugal", "State_Romania", "State_San Marino", "State_Serbia",
                                                                                                                "State_Slovakia", "State_Slovenia", "State_Spain", "State_Sweden",
                                                                                                                "State_Switzerland", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas",
                                                                                                                "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia",
                                                                                                                "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Iowa", "State_Panama",
                                                                                                                "State_Saint Kitts and Nevis", "State_Saint Lucia", "State_Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
                                                                                                                "State_Trinidad and Tobago", "State_Australia", "State_Fiji",
                                                                                                                "State_Kiribati", "State_Marshall Islands", "State_Micronesia",
                                                                                                                "State_Nauru", "State_New Zealand", "State_Palau", "State_Papua New Guinea",
                                                                                                                "State_Samoa", "State_Solomon Islands", "State_Tonga", "State_Tuvalu",
                                                                                                                "State_Vanuatu", "State_Argentina", "State_Bolivia", "State_Brazil",
                                                                                                                "State_Chile", "State_Colombia", "State_Ecuador", "State_Guyana",
                                                                                                                "State_Paraguay", "State_Peru", "State_Suriname", "State_Uruguay",
                                                                                                                "State_Venezuela"), Population = c(436315, 322788, 84665533,
                                                                                                                                                   1382611, 31169272, 103804637, 25540196, 1457723, 60383628, 25353081,
                                                                                                                                                   943256, 91267, 536097, 420799, 287888, 980889, 792094, 702230,
                                                                                                                                                   334450, 118410, 515967, 398281, 659918, 216675, 133583, 176648,
                                                                                                                                                   131878, 941740, 860759, 783373, 188232, 835066, 59606, 992782,
                                                                                                                                                   377751, 720217, 982980, 56697, 644305, 391579, 352490, 143215,
                                                                                                                                                   90170, 817644, 743157, 572583, 595467, 749073, 527312, 914680,
                                                                                                                                                   843229, 978792, 589096, 705171, 750524, 579311, 566931, 800722,
                                                                                                                                                   427156, 753354, 153684, 557458, 987445, 675226, 115191, 664896,
                                                                                                                                                   619308, 274021, 363655, 85848, 66679, 513121, 427450, 985883,
                                                                                                                                                   250922, 406122, 379940, 790470, 300293, 106926, 383729, 851993,
                                                                                                                                                   860519, 607444, 776975, 961911, 769912, 979218)), row.names = c(NA, -88L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

is.not.null <- function(x) !is.null(x)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test",
  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
               notificationItem(
                 text = "RAS",
                 icon("cog", lib = "glyphicon")
               )
  )
)
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data", tabName = "ShowData", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Summary", tabName = "ShowSummary", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ShowData",
            DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "ShowSummary",
            box(width =3,
                h3("Test"),
                helpText("Please Continent, Country and State Combition"),
                uiOutput("continent"),
                uiOutput("country"),
                uiOutput("state")
            ),

            box(width =9,
                DT::dataTableOutput("table_subset")
            )
    )
  )
)

ui = dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)

################################################
################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input,output){

  data <- bind_rows(replicate(5500, df, simplify = FALSE))

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data)){return()}
    DT::datatable(data, options = list(scrollX = T))
  })

  output$continent <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Continent", "Select Continent",choices = c("all", var_continent()), multiple = T)
  })
  output$country <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Country", "Select Country",choices = c("all", var_country()), multiple = T)
  })
  output$state <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "State", "Select State",choices = c("all", var_state()), multiple = T)
  })

  var_continent <- reactive({
    file1 <- data
    if(is.null(data)){return()}
    as.list(c("all", unique(file1$Continent)))
  })

  continent_function <- reactive({
    file1 <- data
    continent <- input$Continent
    continent <<- input$Continent
    if (is.null(continent)){
      return(file1)
    } else {
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Continent %in% continent)
      return (file2)
    }

  })

  var_country <- reactive({
    file1 <- continent_function()
    continent <- input$Continent
    file2 <- data

    if(is.null(continent)){
      as.list(unique(file2$Country))
    } else {
      as.list(unique(file1$Country))
    }
  })

  country_function <- reactive({
    file1 <- data
    country <- input$Country
    country <<- input$Country
    if (is.null(country)){
      return(file1)
    } else {
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Country %in% country)
      return (file2)
    }

  })

  var_state <- reactive({
    file1 <- country_function()
    country <- input$Country
    file2 <- data

    if(is.null(country)){
      as.list(unique(file2$State))
    } else {
      as.list(unique(file1$State))
    }
  })

  state_function <- reactive({
    file1 <- data
    state <- input$State
    state <<- input$State
    if (is.null(state)){
      return(file1)
    } else {
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(State %in% state)
      return (file2)
    }

  })

  df <- reactive({

    file1 <- data
    continent <- input$Continent
    country <- input$Country
    state <- input$State

    if (is.null(continent) & is.not.null(country) & is.not.null(state)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Country %in% country, State %in% state)
    } else if (is.null(country) & is.not.null(continent) & is.not.null(state)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(State %in% state, Continent %in% continent)
    } else if (is.null(state) & is.not.null(country) & is.not.null(continent)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Country %in% country, Continent %in% continent)
    } else if (is.null(continent) & is.null(country) & is.not.null(state)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(State %in% state)
    } else if (is.null(continent) & is.null(state) & is.not.null(country)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Country %in% country)
    } else if (is.null(country) & is.null(state) & is.not.null(continent)){
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Continent %in% continent)
    } else {
      file2 <- file1 %>%
        filter(Country %in% country, State %in% state, Continent %in% continent)
    }
    file2
  })

  output$table_subset <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # validate(
    # need(input$Continent, 'Check that'),
    # need(input$Country, 'Please choose :)')
    # need(input$State, 'Please choose :D')
    # )
    DT::datatable(df(), options = list(scrollX = T))

  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It seems to work well! I personally prefer shinyWidgets::pickerInput as it has the Select All/Deselect All buttons which are neater but your example works

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, is it possible to search in `pickerInput`, for example if I write "a" in country inputs, it should show "australia", "austria", ... ?

Comment: Yes, add `\`live-search\` = TRUE` as follows ```library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    pickerInput(
        inputId = "p1",
        label = "Select all option",
        choices = rownames(mtcars),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                       `live-search` = TRUE)
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485223/add-option-to-scroll-selected-items-once-done-using-selectizeinput and here for all options https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/pickerOptions.html. Alternative is to write `actionsBox = TRUE` and `liveSearch = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks 
If you want update the response, I accept yours ;)

Comment: Great, glad to help. Good luck!