# Add option to scroll selected items once done using selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I'm using selectizeInput to have multiple selections for an input. I have also added a "Select All or None" option that automatically selects all options or nonw (there are A LOT of options). However, my issue is that when it selects all, there are so many options that it shows all of them in the selectizeInput box and it makes my page super long and you have to scroll to the bottom to see anything else in my app. Wondering if there's an option that allows you to have a max number of items selected, and once that is reached, it adds a scroll bar so that the selected items don't all show up and take up the whole page. Any suggestions?

**EDIT: REFER TO THE BELOW**
Here is my next issue: when i utilize the deselect all option from pickerInput, I need to somehow reflect that for the pivot table that either includes all the tickers, includes none of the tickers, or includes some of the tickers. My data is first in a table and then that table is reactive to the inputs. My pivot table then used this data. here is some code: (this just test data)

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

ext <- reactive ({
    name <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
    shortcut <- c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg')
    counter <- c('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg')
    external <- data.frame(name, shortcut, counter)
    return(external)   
})

selections <- reactive({
    temp1 = ext()
    tick <- sort(unique(temp1$counter))
    tick <- tick[order((tick), decreasing = FALSE)]
    list1 <- list(tick = tick)
    return(list1)   
})

# making this reactive to inputs and run button   
extFiltered <- eventReactive(input$runButton, {
    filteredTable <- ext()
    if(!is.null(input$tick)){
      filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick)]
    }
    return(filteredTable)   
})

observe({
    updatePickerInput(session, 'tick', choices = selections()$tick)   
})

# external table that has been filtered from input   
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ extFiltered() })

# pivot table   
output$extPt <- renderPivottabler({
    temp = extFiltered()
    extPt <- PivotTable$new()
    extPt$addData(temp)
    extPt$addColumnDataGroups("name")
   extPt$addRowDataGroups("shortcut")
    extPt$addRowDataGroups("counter")
    extPt$evaluatePivot()
    pivottabler(extPt)   
})

}

ui <- fluidPage(   
pickerInput(inputId = 'tick', label = 'Select Ticker(s)', choices = NULL, 
options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 'live-search' = TRUE), multiple = TRUE) 
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The logic I would like is something like this:

```
if(input$tick == 'Deselect All') {
  filteredTable <- subset(filteredTable, select=-c(filteredTable$counter))
}
else if(input$tick == 'Select All') {
  filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter)]
}
else {
  filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick)]
}
# which would replace this:

if(!is.null(input$tick)){
  filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really require `selectizeInput` I would suggest using `shinyWidgets::pickerInput` with a Select All/Deselect All option built in (using actions-box) as below:

```
pickerInput(
  inputId = 'tick', 
  label = 'Select Ticker(s)', 
  choices = NULL, 
  options = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE,
    `live-search` = TRUE
  ), 
  multiple = TRUE
)
```

and then

```
updatepickerInput(session, 'tick', choices = selections()$tick, 
                     selected = if(input$includeAllTick) selections()$tick)
```

See [shinyWidgets](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/index.html#select-picker).

Example from the link:

[image]

**Update**

After your edit.
All you should need is this line:

```
filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick),]
```

to replace

```
if(!is.null(input$tick)){
  filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick),]
}
```

The Select All/Deselect All buttons do all the work for you.

See below for full working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(pivottabler)
library(shinyWidgets)

ext <- data.frame(
  name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
  shortcut = c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg'),
  counter = c('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(   
  pickerInput(inputId = 'tick', label = 'Select Ticker(s)', choices = NULL, 
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 'live-search' = TRUE), multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton(inputId = 'runButton', label = 'Run'),
  DT::dataTableOutput('table'),
  pivottablerOutput('extPt')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  selections <- reactive({
    temp1 = ext
    tick <- sort(unique(temp1$counter))
    tick <- tick[order((tick), decreasing = FALSE)]
    list1 <- list(tick = tick)
    return(list1)   
  })

  # making this reactive to inputs and run button   
  extFiltered <- eventReactive(input$runButton, {
    filteredTable <- ext
    filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick),]
    return(filteredTable)   
  })

  observe({
    updatePickerInput(session, 'tick', choices = selections()$tick)   
  })

  # external table that has been filtered from input   
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ extFiltered() })

  # pivot table   
  output$extPt <- renderPivottabler({
    temp = extFiltered()
    extPt <- PivotTable$new()
    extPt$addData(temp)
    extPt$addColumnDataGroups("name")
    extPt$addRowDataGroups("shortcut")
    extPt$addRowDataGroups("counter")
    extPt$evaluatePivot()
    pivottabler(extPt)   
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update 2**

After your comments below and the dummy data you have supplied this is what I have come up with. Please test:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(pivottabler)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

ext <- data.frame(
    name = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'),
    shortcut = c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg'),
    counter = c('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'gggg'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(   
    pickerInput(inputId = 'tick', label = 'Select Ticker(s)', choices = NULL, 
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 'live-search' = TRUE), multiple = TRUE),
    actionButton(inputId = 'runButton', label = 'Run'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table'),
    pivottablerOutput('extPt')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    selections <- reactive({
        temp1 = ext
        tick <- sort(unique(temp1$counter))
        tick <- tick[order((tick), decreasing = FALSE)]
        list1 <- list(tick = tick)
        return(list1)   
    })

    # making this reactive to inputs and run button   
    extFiltered <- eventReactive(input$runButton, {
        filteredTable <- ext
        filteredTable <- filteredTable[(filteredTable$counter %in% input$tick),]
        return(filteredTable)   
    })

    observe({
        updatePickerInput(session, 'tick', choices = selections()$tick)   
    })

    # external table that has been filtered from input   
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ extFiltered() })

    # pivot table   
    output$extPt <- renderPivottabler({
        temp = ext %>% 
            select('name', 'shortcut') %>% 
            left_join(extFiltered(), by = c('name', 'shortcut'))
        if(all(is.na(temp$counter))){
            temp = ext %>% 
                select('name', 'shortcut')
            extPt <- PivotTable$new()
            extPt$addData(temp)
            extPt$addColumnDataGroups("name")
            extPt$addRowDataGroups("shortcut")
            # extPt$addRowDataGroups("counter")
            extPt$evaluatePivot()
            pivottabler(extPt)   
        }else{
            temp$counter[is.na(temp$counter)] <- ''
            extPt <- PivotTable$new()
            extPt$addData(temp)
            extPt$addColumnDataGroups("name")
            extPt$addRowDataGroups("shortcut")
            extPt$addRowDataGroups("counter")
            extPt$evaluatePivot()
            pivottabler(extPt)   
        }
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was only using selectize as you can type the beginning of your choice and it shows results (as there are approx 500 items to choose from). Can you do this with pickerInput?

Comment: Amazing, this is what i was looking for initially! Thanks you!

Comment: See all options here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.8/topics/pickerOptions

Comment: Error saying my argument is of length zero in my observe ({ updatePickerInput ....

Comment: since I'm not using the selectize input as previous, I cannot use the input id 'includeAllTick' as that was used for checkbox inputs (in order to make selectize have the option to select all). so the if statement is not functioning. how do i change this?

Comment: now my 'select all' / 'deselect all' is based off the action box. can that be used in my if statement?

Comment: leave the `selected` parameter out. I can't see your full code but you don't need that if statement.

Comment: Ah okay, great that works. And do i include the liveSearch option to be able to type and have suggestions show up? it currently does not allow that

Comment: It should jump to the typed word if you have opened the dropdown and start typing but to show the text you may need to play with those features

Comment: see edited answer above. The parameter is \`live-search\` = TRUE

Comment: can you take a look at my edited question? you've been a lot of help so far just wondering if you can help me with this aprt now!

Comment: Please create a min reprex - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't really include less than that... is that too much info?

Comment: It's too little. It needs to be reproducible for someone else to test. Some dummy data and ideally code that can be copied and run as is to get to your question. - i.e. a minimal full shiny app.

Comment: i've added a test data set let me know if thats sufficient

Comment: You could also look at the package `rpivotTable`

Comment: Thank you for the answers! One thing, i may not have made this clear. I still need the pivot table to show data if 'deselect all' is used. For example, It should still have column data with 'name' and row data with 'shortcut', just no row data with 'counter'. So in the example, the pivot table shows no data when you 'deselect all' counters. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Do you want all of the columns and rows to always show as they are dependent on the selection of the pickerInput? If I understand you correctly it's probably something you can do in the pivot table code. Just add an `if(nrow(extFiltered()) == 0)` and create an empty table.

Comment: So my pivot table takes in 3 sets of data: name, shortcut, counter. I would like to be able to take inputs from counter using pickerInput. So if you 'select all' counters, then the pivot table will have all counters in it. If you 'select specific' counters, then the pivot table will have select counters in it. If you 'select none' counters, then the pivot table will only contain data from name and shortcut, but it will still produce a table. In your code above, if you 'deselect all' counters, the pivot table is empty

Comment: Its just the 'deselect all' option right now makes it so my pivot table has no data. But i still want it to have data, it just won't have the row 'counter', it will only include data from name and shortcut

Comment: Your dummy data isn't right then. You're currently filtering the entire table.

Comment: So how should i do it?

Comment: I have a lot of inputs that get selected and filtered in this table. and then my pivot table takes in the filtered data. But with my other inputs, there doesn't need to be an option 'deselect all' because i always want them (in some capacity) in the table. The 'counter' input is a bit unique though and i just can't figure it out

Comment: You should probably keep that vector separate. Anyway, I have updated the second solution a little to include `temp$counter[is.na(temp$counter)] <- ''` which should do more or less what you want. This question has gone way beyond normal SO parameters. Good luck further.

Comment: @EliBerkow, is it possible to show only 10 contents of my variable in a pickerInput ? thanks

Comment: Do you mean this? `options = list(size = 10)`